# Problems with multiple query mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables -- one called "friends" and other "events".

The table `friends` has columns `id`, `user_id`, and `friend_id`

The table `events` has columns `id`, `user_id`, and  `title_event`

I have six events registered in the "events": my second, 2 and 2 a friend of another friend.

What query will return my friends in the "friends" table and my events and the events of my friends?

I'm using the query below, which returns only the events of my friends. How can I change it to return my events and my friends, too?

Query:

```
SELECT *
 FROM (
       SELECT a.user_id, a.friend_id
         FROM tb_friend a
       WHERE a.user_id = 1
       ) friends, 
tb_events e
WHERE e.user_id = friends.friend_id;
```

Comment: Can you give sample records(3-5), for both the tables and tell me what your query should return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are running into is there is no entry for the original "User_ID = 1", only the friends...  The sample provided by Daan is using a WHERE clause which apparently still isn't working for you.  I suggest your inner query is a UNION to include both you AND your friends as a single result...  This way, you have one qualified list...  If this still does not work, by showing some sample data without actual names (since all your samples are basically IDs anyhow, nothing special to be hidden), it can help others to better offer a solution.  If you are not flexible to provide such sample data, the responses you get from this and the future might be very limited...

```
SELECT *
   FROM 
      ( select 1 as User_ID
        UNION
        SELECT a.friend_id AS User_ID
           FROM tb_friend a
           WHERE a.user_id = 1
       ) QualifiedPeople
      join tb_events e
         on QualifiedPeople.User_ID = e.User_ID
```

Now, If you only want distinct Events, don't do a wild-card showing all people as multiple people who are going to the same event will actually show the event for each person and could show your 8 vs 6 records...  Again, without seeing the sample data, nobody can honestly answer it.

```
SELECT distinct e.id, e.title_event
   FROM ... same rest of query from above
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT a.user_id, a.friend_id
    FROM tb_friend a
    WHERE a.user_id = 1
    ) friends, 
tb_events e
WHERE e.user_id = friends.friend_id OR e.user_id = 1;
```

The only change I made here is adding `OR e.user_id = 1` which should get MySQL to include your own events in the result set.

Comment: I already tried that, but if I add the OR he returns eight results, not 6.

Comment: In that case, can you update your question with some example data?